# Laravel join multiple query result

Tags: php, laravel

when i run the following query, results are listed multiple.

there are 3 records in the table but it lists 5

```
$adverts = Advert::where("category_id", $category->id)
->where("adverts.created_at", "<=", Carbon::now())
->orderBy("id", "DESC")
->select('adverts.*', 'advert_countries.advert_id', 'advert_countries.country_id')
->join("advert_countries", "advert_countries.advert_id", "adverts.id")
->whereIn("advert_countries.country_id", $arr)->paginate(10);
```

---Fixed---

Model :

```
public function countries(){
    return $this->hasMany(AdvertCountry::class, 'advert_id')->orderBy('id', "DESC");
}
```

Controller :

```
$adverts = $adverts->whereHas('countries', function($q) use ($arr){
    $q->whereIn('country_id', $arr);
});
```

Comment: Which query lists `5` instead of `3` rows?

Comment: Needs to list 3. others copy

Comment: You showed 2 queries. Which of them lists 5 rows but you expect it to return only 3 rows?

Comment: 2nd query continuation.
There are 3 unique objects

Comment: Ok, can you combine both queries into 1 instead?

Comment: ok combine query ...

Comment: Can you try the query in this link ? https://pastebin.com/kE1yF6df